# MobileFirst project upgrade fails on Windows 8 appx

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

I'm trying to upgrade a 6.3 project to 7.1 in Studio and the upgrade keeps crashing and closing the project.

If I remove the windows8 project files from my apps, the upgrade works successfully.   I have attached my appx.manifest file in case this helps debug the issue.

10:49:13 AM: [2016-02-09 10:46:18]             Adding WLWin8Native reference and AuthWinRT.targets to the Windows 8 project file 
[2016-02-09 10:46:21] FWLST1226I: Added Authorization Manager Cordova plugin to config.xml (C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\MobileFirst71Prototype\MaximoAnywhere\apps\WorkExecution\iphone\native\config.xml).

[2016-02-09 10:46:21]             Unexpected error during upgrade: **java.lang.NullPointerException at com.worklight.upgrader.upgraders.windows8.AppXManifestUpgrade.upgrade(AppXManifestUpgrade.java:69) 
at** com.worklight.upgrader.WLUpgradeEngine.executeUpgrader(WLUpgradeEngine.java:368) at com.worklight.upgrader.WLUpgradeEngine.performUpgrade(WLUpgradeEngine.java:301) 
at com.worklight.upgrader.WLUpgradeEngine.upgradeProject(WLUpgradeEngine.java:188) at com.worklight.studio.plugin.upgrader.WLUpgraderWorkspaceJob.runInWorkspace(Unknown 
Source) at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38) at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

[2016-02-09 10:46:21]             java.lang.NullPointerException

Here's my package.appxmanifest file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest" xmlns:m2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2013/manifest">
  <Identity Name="a02b50fe-bb55-4be5-8bd9-6c2f93cef175" Version="7.5.2.1" Publisher="CN=application's author"/>
  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>Work Execution</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>IBM</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>images\storelogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>
  <Prerequisites>
    <OSMinVersion>6.3.0</OSMinVersion>
    <OSMaxVersionTested>6.3.0</OSMaxVersionTested>
  </Prerequisites>
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate"/>
  </Resources>
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App" StartPage="www\default\index.html">
      <m2:VisualElements DisplayName="Work Execution" Description="Work Execution" BackgroundColor="#003f69" ForegroundText="light"
        Square150x150Logo="images\logo.png" Square30x30Logo="images\smalllogo.png">
        <m2:SplashScreen Image="images\splashscreen.png"/>
      </m2:VisualElements>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer"/>
    <Capability Name="internetClient"/>
    <Capability Name="picturesLibrary"/>
    <DeviceCapability Name="webcam"/>
    <DeviceCapability Name="location"/>
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

Comment: Also, do you have some details on which files get upgraded during the upgrade process for Android, iOS, and Windows8.  I want to make sure I take advantage of the upgrades.

Comment: What is the exact build version of the MFP 7.1 studio?

Comment: 7.1.0.00-20160206-1558

Answer (score 0):

somehow I had some invalid XML in there for my VisualElements elements.  Once I fixed the manifest's VisualElements section to look like this, the upgrade went through.

```
 <VisualElements BackgroundColor="#003f69" Description="Inspection" DisplayName="Inspection" ForegroundText="light" Logo="images\logo.png" SmallLogo="images\smalllogo.png" ToastCapable="true">
        <SplashScreen Image="images\splashscreen.png"/>
      </VisualElements>
```

Comment: Another question for you, after my upgrade, Windows8 build now fails. Should this file move? Error while reading XML file: C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\MobileFirst71Prototype\MaximoAnywhere\apps\AssetAudit\windows8\native\AssetAudit.Windows8\package.appxmanifest (The system cannot find the path specified) Nested exception: C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\MobileFirst71Prototype\MaximoAnywhere\apps\AssetAudit\windows8\native\AssetAudit.Windows8\package.appxmanifest (The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: It was originally under my AssetAudit.Shared directory.., but now it seems like it's checking under AssetAudit.Windows8.